# Axios call works inside Vue.js mounted() but not inside function

Tags: vue.js, axios

This works:

```
mounted(soc=1) {
    const params = { society: soc }
    axios.get('/ajax/load-centers', { params })
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
}
```

This is triggered by a successful event, but it doesn't return a response:

```
loadCenters: function (soc) {
    const params = { society: soc }
    axios.get('/ajax/load-centers', { params })
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
}
```

This is the event info:

```
name:"loadCenters"
type:"$emit"
source:"<Root>"
payload:Array[1]
0:"1"
```

Comment: How do you listen for an event ?

Comment: did your app reload after the event?

Comment: add return `return axios.get('/ajax/load-centers', { params }).then(response => console.log(response.data))`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
async loadCenters: function (soc) {
    const params = { society: soc }
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/ajax/load-centers', { params })
      console.log( 'Request Executed' )
      console.log( data )
    } catch ( e ) {
      console.log(e)
    }
}
```